# Display Google Docs in Compact View

Tags: google-docs

Apparently, there is a way to view a Google Docs document as one long scrolling page (like a web page), instead of the antiquated default with separate pages. It is called [Compact View](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1252622?hl=en), and it actually [used to be the default view](https://yukisays.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/google-docs-adds-pagination-feature-how-to-turn-it-off/).

Currently, I can't find how to enable it. [This](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1252622?hl=en) Google Support page seems to imply it is tied to the "Compact Controls" setting, but I think someone at Google got confused about the similar names and made a mess of that page.

Comment: Related: [How do I suppress Google Documents' display of a hard page break as white space on the previous page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69215/354)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

To toggle between the view that shows the break pages and the one that hide them, on a Google document click on **View > Print layout** .

The following snapshot shows a document having two pages with the print layout turned off:

[image: Print layout off]

An alternative method to turn off the print layout view is to double click on the space between pages

## Remarks

There are several ways to submit feedback to Google,

1. Use the feeback form at the bottom of [referred help article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1252622?hl=en)
2. On a Google document, click on Help > Report a problem
3. Post your feedback at the Google Docs Help Forum

Comment: Excellent! The double-click shortcut is especially cool!